# Entry Point of a DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, ninject

I've a `c# .net` `WPF` application, now i need to register something(basically kernel of `NInject` `IoC` pattern) that has been used by the `BLL` and `DAL` layer.

I want to know the entry point or something like that for the `dll` where i could put that code(kernel registration).

For `WPF` section, i use `App.xaml.cs`, for `WCF` section i use `Global.asax.cs` as they are the entry point of these things. But what about standalone `dlls`, what is their entry point.

One approach is that, i could add a static class in my dll which fulfil this purpose and from `app.xaml.cs` i call this method of BLL and register my kernels. But this seems more like a workaround than approach.

Please guide me for something more to the point and logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Container configuration is done in the composite root of your application (The point where your code is called the first time). As you already said, in case of WPF this is the App.xaml.cs. Here you register the components of ALL layers. Preferably you have to UI code in another assembly than the App.xaml. This way the creation of the spplication is completely separated from the execution of the code.

I suggest to read Mark Seemans book where this is described in detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my UI layer or app.xaml.cs does not contain the reference of BLL layer, there is a some other layer between UI and BLL Layer and I at no cost wants to add the reference of BLL layer directly in my UI layer.                                                              Even still this is not the feasible approach, if there is nothing specfic about that, i'll go for the book, but please gimme its name.

Comment: You missunderstood my answer. The bootstrapping assembly that contains the app.xaml does exactly one thing. It sets up your application. The UI layer goes into another assembly. In this case it is absolutely no problem to reference all layers. If you want to reuse some of the layers and replace others in another application you just replace this bootstrapper.

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't allow to run code on assembly loading, and static class constructors are lazily executed on first access to the class. However the CLR supports a static "assembly constructor", so to speak, which is executed when the assembly is first loaded. Mind you, references are still loaded lazily unless you put in special attributes to mark a referenced assembly to be loaded eagerly.

If you want you could put a static constructor into the assembly module through ildasm/ilasm. You could probably make some scripts to automate this on build.

I didn't do this myself yet, so I can't give any examples. Though if you consider doing it I can maybe dig up some links.

Comment: +1 For added searchability, The term Module Initializer is often used wrt this

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like your wanting a "plug-in" model where the app can dynamically discover components that are available. If so, then [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) might be a better option.

MEF seems to work well for cases where the app might not know about all it's dependencies ahead of time. Dependency injection, on the other hand, assumes that your app is fairly knowledgeable about these dependencies ahead of time.

I don't know if this is what you're after, but it might be worth a look.